# JTango's Unity SDK sample code : "mesh.vertices = vertices" fail?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, google-project-tango

```
Debug.log(vertices.Length.toString());    // show not 0!!--added myself
Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
mesh.vertices = vertices;
mesh.triangles = triangles;             
Debug.log(mesh.vertices.Length.toString());   // show 0??? --added myself
```

this is a sample code from google tango SDK(I added the two `debug.log` code).
vertices and triangles is got from Dll api directly. I found that when vertices.length is larger than some number (too many 3Dreconstructed mesh according to the dll), for example 10000. the code `mesh.vertices = vertices;` will fail ,which leads to the second log shows `0` (of course the first log shows a number larger than `0`).

I don't know why?

Answer (score 2):

Unity has a limit of 65535 vertices for the mesh vertex list due to using 16bit index buffers internally.

Can you confirm this is the limit you are seeing?

-Tom

Comment: this may be the answer, or at least gives me a direction to dig in! I will have a try. Thx!